# I am getting access denied when moving files in tsql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am getting access denied errors when I move files from server1 to server2.  Please advise how I should get past this error in my tsql script.

I used xp_cmdshell 'move d:\files \server2'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tsql uses the permissions of the account used to start the SQL Server instance.  To see the account used, open the services control panel, locate the SQL Server service, goto properties and then logon tab.  You probably need to change this to an account that has the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can give permission to this user for database folder:
NT Service\MSSQLSERVER